# Issue with resizing my app

Tags: html, css, optimization, mobile, resize

I have problem with resizing my app. On my PC everything is ok but on my phone not completely. I have monitor 4:3 but when I emulate resizing to 16:9 ,using "ctrl+shift+i" in chrome, everything works ok. 
HTML:

```
<head>
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
</head>
<body

<table class="tableinmenu">
 <tr id="proportionone">
    <td id="picture"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="proportiontwo">
    <td>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Text"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.tableinmenu {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 20px 5px;
}

#proportionone {
height: 80%;
}

#proportiontwo {
height: 20%;
}

#picture {
background-image: url("img.jpg");
background-position: center;    
background-size: 100% 100%;
border: 20px solid white;
border-bottom: none;
border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
opacity: 0;
}

#button {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #c3f;
font-family: Florence, cursive;
font-size: xx-large;
color: white;
border: 20px solid white;
border-top: none;
border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
opacity: 0;
}
```

PC version:[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHnK7.png)
Mobile version:[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrcD8.png)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this relate somehow with Android, or it's only the OS of the device you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understend your question. I have Android 5.1.1 on my device.

Comment: You used the `Android` tag, but I think that you are not writing an Android app. It that's the case, please change the tag to `html` or something.

Comment: I'm writing an android app using PhoneGap which means using html. But ok, I can change this tag.

Comment: No, it should be fine with that. One notice though, add the images in the question, not as external links.